# Indexed 15 million customers but query still takes almost 5mins to return results

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, entity-attribute-value

I have 15 million customers data in 3 columns and the columns indexed in each:

1. customers

   - `Index ix_disabled_customer_id on zen_customers(customers_id, disabled);`
2. customer_attribute

   - `Index ix_attribute_id_and_name on`zen_customers`(attribute_id, attribute_name);`
3. customer_attribute_value.

   - `` Index ix_attribute_id_and_customer_id on `zen_customers`(customers_id, attribute_id); ``

I am trying to filter the customers using Gender and it takes too long to return the results.

Following is the query

```
SELECT tcav.customers_id AS customers_id 
FROM customer_attribute_value tcav
JOIN customer_attribute tca
JOIN customers zc
WHERE tcav.attribute_id = tca.attribute_id
    AND tca.attribute_name = "Gender"
    AND tcav.attribute_value = "M"
    AND zc.customers_id = tcav.customers_id
    AND  zc.disabled = 0;
```

[**Image Added for Explain Extended plan**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9SAZ.png)

It would really appreciated if I could get ideas to optimize this filtering. Thanks

Comment: Pls include the result of the explain.

Comment: Please go to the following link to see the Explain extended plan. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9SAZ.png

I have added to the question as well.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 3 tables.

Answer (score 0):

First, using ON clauses instead of the WHERE clause for joining tables is recommended. It is unlikely to have any effect on performance, but it does help improve the ability to see what columns relate which tables.

```
SELECT tcav.customers_id AS customers_id 
FROM tulip_customer_attribute_value tcav
JOIN tulip_customer_attribute tca
ON tcav.attribute_id = tca.attribute_id
JOIN zen_customers zc
ON zc.customers_id = tcav.customers_id
WHERE tca.attribute_name = "Gender"
AND tcav.attribute_value = "M"
AND zc.disabled = 0
```

Add the following indexes:

```
tulip_customer_attribute (attribute_name,attribute_id)

tulip_customer_attribute_value (attribute_id,attribute_value,customers_id)
```

The order of the columns in the indexes is important.

Answer (score -1):

EAV schema has many problems.  In this case, you are expending a lot of space and time looking up the 'gender' when it could more efficiently be simply in the main table.

Your schema has made it immensely worse by normalizing out the values, rather than putting them in the attribute table.

Follow the tag [entity-attribute-value] for further enlightenment.

Until you seriously revamp the schema, the performance will go from bad to terrible as the data grows.